# Can the Twitter API return partial responses?

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi

Katy Perry's latest 140 character tweet is 3822 characters if you get the full response from Twitter's API ( `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json`).

Does the Twitter API support partial responses / field masks so that we can only receive the data we care about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) lists a couple of options you can use.

`trim_user=true` will remove a bunch of data about the user. You'll still get some other metadata as well.

`count=1` will get you just the most recent tweet - nothing else.